# Using Stacks in ImageMagick to Selectively Blur Part of the Image

Tags: text, imagemagick, blur, annotate, stack

I'm trying to annotate some text onto a base image with a dropshadow. I don't like the results I get from using the -shadow option, so I'm putting down the text, blurring it, then putting down the text again in white, a few pixels offset from the shadow. Here's the command I'm using:

```
convert base_image.jpg \
        -font TT0590M_.ttf \
        -fill gray30 \
        -annotate +0+0 '' -gravity North \
        -annotate +72+32 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM' \
        -blur 0x4 \
        -fill white \
        -annotate +72+27 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM' \
        combined.png
```

My problem is that the -blur option is blurring not only the first layer of text, but the underlying base image as well. I only want the first layer of text to blur, not the base image.

I read up a little on using stacks and tried to isolate the first layer of text and the blur command using `\( \)` around that part, such as in the following:

```
convert base_image.jpg \
        -font TT0590M_.ttf \
        -fill gray30 \
        -annotate +0+0 '' -gravity North \
        \( -annotate +72+32 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM' \
        -blur 0x4 \) \
        -fill white \
        -annotate +72+27 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM' \
        combined.png
```

The results are the same - both the text shadow and the underlying base image are getting blured. I'm afraid I'm not having much luck understanding stacks or what other commands I should be using to get the effect I'm after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As so often happens, I've continued to bang away at this since posting the question and I've managed to solve it on my own.

The important change is that I started with a blank, transparent canvas instead of starting with the base image. After I get the text right, I insert the base image into the stack, swap the order of the two images in the stack, and then composite them with a compose type of "screen", which lays the one overtop of the other.

One other note of import: the -channel RGBA is needed so that the blurring works in conjunction with the transparency of the text layer, due to a peculiarity in the way that IM works. Why this is necessary is explained [on this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/convolve/#blur).

Also, on Windows systems (.bat file instead of shell script), the single quotes need to be double quotes and the backslashes "\" need to be carets "^", or it all comes crashing down.

The script below is the final, working result (*nix version):

```
convert  \
    -size 500x500 xc:transparent \
    -font TT0590M_.ttf \
    -annotate +0+0 '' -gravity North \
    -fill gray30 \
    -annotate +75+35 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR\nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR' \
    -channel RGBA \
    -blur 0x4 \
    -fill white \
    -annotate +72+30 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR\nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR' \
    -insert 0 base_image.jpg \
    -swap 0,1 \
    -composite -compose screen \
    combined.png
```